# How to fix "Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined" error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I created an application using Firebase-CLI and I wrote a code to redirect when the user logged in to another location also when he did not. But when I try the serve it's not working

Here is my html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JTM Check</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/6.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/6.0.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
    <script>
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
          // User is signed in.
        } else {
          // No user is signed in.
        }
      });    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the error

> (index):15 Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
>
> at (index):15
>
> (anonymous) @ (index):15

Comment: Are you running this on a server? If so, check if the links to the firebase scripts are working, e.g. the scripts are available. Are you running this locally? Do you have a webserver running to serve these scripts?

Comment: Running locally, and yes I have nginx web server on my computer but it's closed

Answer (score 2):

remove `defer` from your scripts

when present, it specifies that the script is executed when the page has finished parsing. so your script is executing before `firebase` is loaded